# Basic question about Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis

The problem is:
Let $f \in L^{1}(R) \cap C(R)$ . Supose that $f$ is positive. Show that $|\hat{f}(\xi)| < |\hat{f}(0)|$ for all $\xi \neq 0$.

My idea: By the definition of the Fourier transform we have $$|\hat{f}(\xi)| \leq |\hat{f}(0)|$$

But i am not seeing a contradiction if i have the equality for $\xi \neq 0$.

Someone can give me a hint?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $f \geqslant 0$, we have $\hat{f}(0) \geqslant 0$. For $\xi \neq 0$, pick an $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $e^{-i\alpha}\hat{f}(\xi) \geqslant 0$. Then

$$\begin{align}
\hat{f}(0) - \lvert \hat{f}(\xi)\rvert
&= \hat{f}(0) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) e^{-i(\alpha + t\xi)}\,dt\\
&= \hat{f}(0) - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\cos (\alpha + t\xi)\,dt\\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\left(1-\cos (\alpha + t\xi)\right)\,dt.
\end{align}$$

Since $1 - \cos (\alpha + t\xi) \geqslant 0$ everywhere, and has only isolated zeros, we have, due to the non-negativity and continuity of $f$

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)\left(1-\cos (\alpha + t\xi)\right)\,dt = 0 \iff f \equiv 0.$$

So if $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}) \cap C(\mathbb{R})$, $f \geqslant 0$ and $f \not\equiv 0$, we have the strict inequality

$$\lvert \hat{f}(\xi)\rvert < \hat{f}(0)$$

for all $\xi\neq 0$.

Comment: Nice solution! thanks!